# What is the proper flag for questions that ask for code but provide none themselves

Tags: discussion

I have seen a lot of questions where users say "I have input `x` and I want output `y`" but they themselves have not written or provided code that attempts to get from `x` to `y`. Should these questions be flagged?

If so what flag should I use? I'm inclined to use the **too broad** or the **unclear what they're asking** flag but it doesn't feel like it's too broad or unclear what they're asking. Should there be a new flag?

The case that I see for not flagging is that the user might have code they can provide and should be prompted to provide it via the comments. If they say they have no code does the question get flagged at that point?

Edit:
The main point of this question is not whether or not code should be required - I completely agree there are valid cases where code shouldn't be required - but for the cases of people saying "give me the code" to a very specific problem. Should **too broad** function as the flag for that type of question?

Comment: Mostly _too broad_ or _unclear what you're asking_.

Comment: Okay that's what I've been using but I feel like it isn't strictly too broad or unclear what they're asking? Should there be a new flag for this?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I edited my question to show how it's different from that question. Let me know if it still feels like a duplicate though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common misconception, but there is no absolute requirement for code in a question. If someone doesn't have any idea how to do what they're asking, that's fine. We wouldn't benefit by having them post some junk code.

If the question is actually unclear or too broad (which such questions often are), then vote to close it as such. But a lack of code in the question is not an automatic disqualification.

Comment: Even if it's something like a homework question where they're asking for an answer but have no idea how to begin? I'm not sure what type of answers people would be expected to provide without giving away the solution

Comment: Those often are too broad. And they'd generally still be too broad even if they had some code.

Answer (score 2):

> I have seen a lot of questions where users say "I have input x and I want output y" but they themselves have not written or provided code that attempts to get from x to y. Should these questions be flagged?

These questions are usually ***too broad***, because there are many more than one way to achieve the wanted result.

Asking such kind of questions isn't wanted, as they don't specify a concrete problem with attempted code (thus ***unclear what you're asking*** also often applies), that could be resolved in a straightforward and concise way.